# How to use a c++ library with python?

Tags: python, c++

I have the .so file of a complex project written in C++. Is there a way I can use this library with python ? I'm not supposed to make any code changes to the existing C++ files. Is writing C++ wrapper around each file with boost.py the only way? Will the runtime of the code take a hit by doing this ?

Comment: You risk downvotes for saying "C/C++" without a very good explanation why both languages are relevant for your question. (I did not downvote by the way.)

Comment: @NickyC I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to call C++ code from Python with [`Boost.Python`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/).

> The Boost Python Library is a framework for interfacing Python and
>   C++. It allows you to quickly and seamlessly expose C++ classes
>   functions and objects to Python, and vice-versa, using no special
>   tools -- just your C++ compiler. It is designed to wrap C++ interfaces
>   non-intrusively, so that you should not have to change the C++ code at
>   all in order to wrap it, making Boost.Python ideal for exposing
>   3rd-party libraries to Python. The library's use of advanced
>   metaprogramming techniques simplifies its syntax for users, so that
>   wrapping code takes on the look of a kind of declarative interface
>   definition language (IDL).

Comment: the question specifically says changing the c++ source code is impossible

Comment: Did you read the answer? It says *you should not have to change the C++ code at all*.

Comment: Sure, but did you read the question? I presume OP knows it's possible to use Boost.Python ("*boost.py").

Comment: Did you read the linked docs rustyx?

Answer (score 1):

**SWIG** is an option:
[SWIG TUTORIAL](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

Although it can get quite frustrating to debug core dumps :)